# I want to be able to speak more casual Japanese. I just wanted to know if it was possible to drop です out of a sentence. example: これは犬

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, particles

Could I drop です out of a sentence? I want to be able to speak more casual Japanese. I just wanted to know if it was possible to drop です out of a sentence. example: これは犬

Comment: you certainly can do that. but it’s not a sentence. it’s a bit like a russian saying, “i want to speak more casually, how about if i drop ‘is’ from this sentence: ‘this, dog’”

Answer (score 2):

I mean, it would make sense, but it's like saying in English: "is dog". So it wouldn't be grammatically correct. You can say これは犬だ, or just keep it normal. Also saying it like this isn't really formal, so I'd keep it with これは犬です.

-a native Japanese speaker